# AngularJS ng-repeat elements don't align well when using Bootstrap col-md-2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using AngularJS ng-repeat to render a product list and also using bootstrap col-md-2 to make it show 6 products each row. I pasted a brief version of my code as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Grid System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap- theme.min.css">
<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
<style type="text/css">
    p{
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="item in items">
           <img src="{{itme.imgURL}}" />
           <p>{{item.title}}</p>
           <div>
                <a href="{{item.productURL}}" />
           </div>
       </div> 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

However, some of the products' titles are too long and will be shown in two or more lines. In this case, the elements shown is not aligned very well. To see the alignment problem, please try the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Grid System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap- theme.min.css">
<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">        </script>
<style type="text/css">
    p{
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 1 test</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 2</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 3</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 4</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 5</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 6</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 7</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 8</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 9</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 10</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 11</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Box 12</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Box 7 shows under Box 2 instead of under Box 1.

I knew we can add clearfix div before Box 7 or we can put element 7 - 12 in a new bootstrap row. But the problem is that I used ng-repeat, so I don't have control on each of the element.

So could someone give me some suggestion on how to make all elements aligned well?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What about putting the clearfix inside the repeat, but wrap it in an `ng-if`?  You could use the index of the repeat to only include the clearfix at the right point.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like a custom directive that will be call in each item of your repeat, and then, when it is the last item you use the setTimeout() for giving a time to render the html and call a function that will get the Height.

```
angular.module('box').directive('myRepeatDirective', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                scope.$eval('resizeBoxes()');
            }); 
        }
    };
})
```

In the method resizeBoxes I'm using JQuery to get the max height and in the end setting all "< p >" with the same height.

```
.controller("boxController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.boxes = boxes;

    $scope.resizeBoxes = function () {
        var maxHeight = -1;

        $('.col-md-2 p').each(function () {
            maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
        });
        $('.col-md-2 p').each(function () {
            $(this).height(maxHeight);
        });
    }
}])
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="container" ng-controller="boxController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="b in boxes" my-repeat-directive>
            <p>{{b.label}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the code in the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q1MvHXp3t2q5VRW0jdRQ?p=preview)

Comment: well done. It's a good moment to call resizeBoxes(). I would change setTimeout+$eval by a simple $timeout, to reduce code.

Answer (score 0):

I put [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardkevin84/413kn4em/3/) that may help. Note that the fiddle does almost nothing without the BS include; just copy the method into your project.

It's a pretty simple js solution I pulled from a project where I kept running into the same problem. (I've been meaning to build it into a module for some time, because I see a ton of devs running into the same issue)

Essentially, the `sizesiblings` method takes a jq selector, and monitors the elements' physical dimensions, keeping them uniform according to the amount of vertical space the "hungriest" element wants.

#### your use case may be something like...

Well, I started to put it here, but it got unwieldy. Rather, I updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardkevin84/413kn4em/3/) :)

A call to `sizesiblings('.repeated-items>.col-md-2');` should make all the divs behave.